# Lock two timers on different object

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, locking

I have several objects which require same function to be executed at different time. Some objects of them are mutual exclusive, some are not.

So to be short, I illustrate this short example with only two timers

Do these two timers work on parallel? Or should I use a different approach?

```
class MyTimer:Timer
{
   private static int count=0;
   public int Id {get; private set;}
   public MyTimer(){ Id= count++;}
}

...
object[] lockers = new object[2]{new object(), new object()};
MyTimer[] timers = new MyTimer[2]{ new MyTimer(), new MyTimer()};
...
/* somewhere */
timers[0].Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;
timers[1].Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;
timers[0].Start();
timers[1].Start();
...
private void Time_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer timer = sender as MyTimer;
    lock(lockers[timer.Id])
    {
        /* part of code depends on timer.Id*/
    }
}
```

EDIT AFTER  Kennyzx answer (I did not want to write too much code but I was not clear above about what I wanted ask):

```
interface IWorker 
  {
   void DoSomething();
  }
class MyTimer:Timer
{   
   public int Id {get; private set;}
   public IWorker Worker;
   public MyTimer(int id){ Id=id;}
}
...
object[] lockers = new object[2]{new object(), new object()};
MyTimer[] timers = new MyTimer[3]{ new MyTimer(0), new MyTimer(1),new MyTimer(1)};
...
/* somewhere */
timers[0].Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;
timers[1].Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;
timers[2].Elapsed += Time_Elapsed;

timers[0].Worker = Worker_A; // implement IWorker
timers[1].Worker = Worker_B; // implement IWorker
timers[2].Worker = Worker_C; // implement IWorker
timers[0].Start();    timers[1].Start();    timers[2].Start();
...
private void Time_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer timer = sender as MyTimer;
    lock(lockers[timer.Id])
    {
        timer.Worker.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

In this new example Worker_B and Worker_C are mutually exlusive (because timer.Id is the same). But Worker_A can work in parallel with them. 
Is it correct way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Do these two timers work on parallel？**

For System.Timers.Timer, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread, which mean the event handlers can run on parellel.

But your `lock` statement is somehow problematic, how can you guarantee mutual exclusive? Should lock on the same instance of object.

```
object locker = new object();

...

private void Time_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: I updated the question adding a more detailed one. I hope I am clear now

Comment: You code works, but the classes are not well-designed, from an OO perspective. Specifically, MyTimer's Id property and the lockers array serve the purpose of synchronization, but they are not directly related to the real resources that must be accessed mutually exclusive. There is [a site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for code review in StackExchange, you can post your code there and ask for help to improve your code.